# What components do I need to connect a phone to my device via Bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth, antenna, microchip, iphone

I have a phone I want to connect to a docking station I am making, via Bluetooth for as cheap as possible. As I understand the situation, all I need is something that can pick up a bluetooth signal from a smart phone, and relay it to a chip (in digital form preferably).

Could this purely be done by a bluetooth antenna? Or does this antenna need to be connected to other components to process the information it is receiving, in which case, it would be better off getting a module like the microchip RN-42?

Apologies if this is a naive question, have tried to do my research but I do not know enough electronic technical lingo to work it out myself.

Comment: If you're asking these questions, you need a module.

Comment: not sure I really understand your question.... do you need to transfer audio/data over bluetooth? if not, just use a REED switch

Comment: Your question is unclear to me, do you need to detect when a device with the bluetooth on is inserted in the station or do you need the data stream to be collected by a micro? Please clarify what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Bluetooth is an active digital protocol over 2.4ghz rf. In order to communicate over it, you need the analog stage (antenna, rf amp circuitry, filtering) and you need the digital stage (protocol management frames, demodulation, low level profiles and communication). You could do a bluetooth setup from scratch, by investing a lot of time/money into hardware and software revision. It is not a trivial task.

A module is a prebuilt solution, with end user in mind.  Use a module.